# Include padding in size of div

Tags: html, css, width, padding

Here is an image to explain my problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CP3C.png]

I need the padding to be factored in when the `width: 50%;` is done.
If I don't, the first `div`'s width will actually be `50% + 2em` because the padding had not been accounted for.

How can I count the padding in the width calculation, or is there a workaround for having two equal-sized but padded `div`s?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sMuCY/

Code for testing:

```
<div style="padding:1em;float:left;width:50%;background-color:#faa">
    This div has 50% width, 1em padding, float left
</div>
<div style="background-color:#0f0;padding:1em">
    This is a div with 1em padding
</div>

<hr>

<div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#faa">
    This div has 50% width and float left
</div>
<div style="background-color:#0f0">
    This is a normal div
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing` property to change the default behaviour of the box-model:

```
div {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sMuCY/1/)

Another demo to test the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/sMuCY/2/

Reading: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Alos note, that `-moz-` preffix is required in Firefox. IE supports this property starting from 8th version.